# gacutil postbuild event exists with code 1

Tags: visual-studio-2010, gacutil

I am trying to register and assembly in the GAC on a post-build event.  Here's my post-build command

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\x64\gacutil.exe" /if "$(TargetPath)"

I am on x64/Windows 7/VS2010.  I am running VS2010 as an administrator and I have UAC turned off (which is pretty much all that my google-fu is finding for this problem).

The post build is exiting with code 1 for the all 4 instances of gacutil.exe I can find on my machine.

Anyone know a way around this?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: This actually started working after a rebuild of my dev machine.  So I am not sure what the issue was.

Comment: The error that displays in the shell is "Failure adding assembly to the cache:   The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."

Answer (score 14):

Copy the full post-build event command string (e.g. ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\x64\gacutil.exe" /if "D:\ProjectFolder\Project.Name\bin\Debug\Project.Name.dll" to the clip board, open a command prompt as an administrator, paste the post-build event, and press enter to execute. You'll get a more descriptive explanation of the exit code.

In my case, I had my project set to build to the wrong target framework. I switched it from .Net 4 to .Net 3.5 and the error went away.

Best of luck

Comment: Following this suggestion, I had an access denied error.  That was fixed by running Visual Studio as Administrator.

Comment: This is a good suggestion. In my particular case the output error was that I forgot to sign the assembly.

Comment: In my case the .dll was used by another process. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

SOLUTION:

Try to run Visual Studio as ADMIN to install things in GAC... :)

Answer (score 2):

Mine is usually solved by iisreset.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your post build script is incorrect....Try using "$(DevEnvDir)....\SDK\v2.0\Bin\GacUtil.exe" /i "$(TargetPath)" /f

Answer (score 1):

OS:  Windows server 2012

.Net frame work 4.5

The path needs to be: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\gacutil.exe

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I was able to fix it by:

1. Finding and stopping any other processes that had a handle open on the dll using [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653)
2. Uninstalling the assembly with "gacutil /u AssemblyName"
3. Increasing the Assembly Version Number in Project Properties -> Assembly information

After these steps my post build step started working again.

Comment: The only process that is showing attachment to my dll is `devenv.exe` (VS itself)?