# How to choose which gacutil.exe path to set in my environment variables?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sdk, environment-variables, gacutil

I moved a project from .NET 3.5 to .NET 4.6.1. Now when I try to build (with the following as my post-build event command) I get the this error:

> ```
> gacutil -if "$(TargetPath)"
> ```
>
> The command "gacutil -if "[xyz.dll]"" exited with code 1

I referenced this stack overflow answer: [gacutil postbuild event exists with code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6656235/gacutil-postbuild-event-exists-with-code-1)

The problem appears to be the fact that there is a new version of the GacUtil that needs to be used with .NET 4.0 projects and above.

I determined that this is the path to my current gacutil. My Path environment variable is set to this:

> `C:\>where gacutil`
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\gacutil.exe

After navigating to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows, I see that there are several different SDKs versions to choose from.

- v7.0A
- v7.1A
- v8.0
- V8.0A
- V8.1
- V8.1A
- V10.0A

I assume I just choose the path to the gacutil in latest version?

What the new Path environment variable would be:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.7.2 Tools`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be safe to use the latest version, and I would recommend using at least v10.0A (4.6.1) since that's what Navigator requires.  Just make sure you don't have paths to tools folders for several versions of .NET as that can lead to some problems during installations if there is a mismatch.